# How to ignore a mongo pipeline stage conditionally based on field values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
addFields
{
  "items.product.title": "some title",
  "items.product.code": "some code"
}
```

This is an **addFields** stage in my query pipeline. Sometimes items field is an empty array before the execution of this stage and some other times it has items which also need product field to be added (in this stage). I want to make a condition for the execution or complete ignorance of this stage based on that. So, when items is an empty array I want to completely skip this stage and keep **items** untouched (leave it as an empty array), otherwise add new fields **inside items**.

Case 1 - items is empty:

```
// data before stage:
{
_id: "some id"
items: []
}
// expected output after stage (nothing is changed):
{
_id: "some id"
items: []
}
```

Case 2- items is not empty:

```
// data before stage:
{
_id: "some id"
items: [
 {
   item_id: "some id"
   count: 5  
 }
]
}
// expected output after stage:
{
_id: "some id"
items: [
 {
   item_id: "some id"
   count: 5  
   product  // product needs to be added
   {
      title: "some title" // these need to be added
      code: "some code"
   }
 }
]
}
```

How can I create a condition for the execution of a stage?

Comment: can you share sample data and sample aggregation pipeline? DId you checked $cond operator, you can check condition and decide what to set based on your data.

Comment: this is a `$set` stage? you are giving us paths without us to be able to see the data. so its hard to write a query

Comment: ok that helps, but what should happen if items have like 2 members? you want to add that title/code in all members? in a specific member based on index? in a specific member based on `item_id`?

Comment: @Takis I just want to add title and code to all members of items (the values come from some other field which is not important)

Comment: ok i updated it, the bellow add it in all items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- map over items and add the product(`$mergeObjects`) in all members
- you dont need condition, if array is empty, map will do nothing, leaving the array empty.

*in general you cant skip a `$addFields` stage but you can keep the old value based on condition, here if array is empty `$map` does nothing anyway, so we dont even need condition to keep the old value.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wN_3oraZz2j)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "items": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$items",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$i",
              {
                "product": {
                  "title": "some title",
                  "code": "some code"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "as": "i"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. The stage is an addFields stage and I want to check items array. If items array is empty, I don't want anything to happen at all and if it's not, I want to add some fields to items (like product title and code that I've written above.

Comment: see the edit, if you can give us sample simplified data next time, it would be much easier,
i am not sure now also, if i know what you want, without data in, and expected data out
but maybe will help

Comment: I just updated the question with expected input and output in both cases. Would you please see it again?

Comment: i think this time will be what you need

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in order to include or ignore a pipeline stage is to handle the conditional logic above/outside the aggregate method.

So if I have an $match stage and a (conditional) $add stage, I'd assign each to a variable. Then have some if/then logic for the condition, based on variables passed to the custom resolver function. Inside the aggregate method, use the result of the condition.

E.g.:

```
const stage 1 =  {
  $match: {}
}
const stage 2 =  {
  $add: {}
}

const agg = <condition> ? [stage1, stage2] : [stage1]

db.collection.aggregate([
  ...agg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const function = async () => {

const pipeline = [];

"condition" && pipeline.push(stage)
"another condition" && pipeline.push(another stage)

const response = await model.aggregate([...pipeline])

}
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)